# PDF viewer for flutter that supports 64-bit versions

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have a flutter app that requires a PDF viewer, but all packages that i have found on pub.dev require that you add the following ndk filter in your build.gradle.

```
ndk {
   abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
}
```

But if I understand it correct, this will cause the appbundle to not include a 64-bit version, which Google Play now requires. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm therefore asking you for help about how I can include a PDF viewer in the app, while still being able to upload the app to both Google Play and App Store.

Answer (score 0):

This following code works:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
}
```

This may make your APK file to have a bigger size, but the App Bundle, required by Google Play, will have the same size as before.

So, for development, I recommend commenting "arm64-v8a', 'x86_64' architectures to reduce your compilation time.

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
}
```